# Spring + Vaadin annotation @Autowired in UI

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, vaadin

i am working now with Spring + Vaadin JSP integration. I am working on admin panel for internet store.
I had already done Spring server and successfully added Vaadin UI into it, but annotation( @Autowired and etc.) in vaadin UI is not working, because the server is devided on two servlets(dispacherServlet and vaadinServlet). The most of server pages work with dispacher servlet and only admin panel work with Vaadin. I need connect JPA Repository and Service to vaadin UI. Could you please help me fix it and connect service to UI.
UI Class:

```
@Theme("valo")
@Title("Administration panel")
@SpringUI
public class Administration extends UI {

    @Autowired
    LoginService service;  //null

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        setContent(layout);
        TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
        tabs.setSizeFull();
        UsersTab usersTab= new UsersTab();
        CategoriesTab categoriesTab = new CategoriesTab();
        tabs.addComponent(usersTab.getLayout());
        tabs.addComponent(categoriesTab.getLayout());
        layout.addComponent(tabs);
    }
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/administration","/administration/*","/VAADIN/*"},asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = Administration.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class AdministrationVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to code, instead provide meaningful code snippets here in your question. You can [edit] it to add the code.

Comment: Did you follow the [Vaadin Spring Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring)? I guess you don't use spring boot, so have a look at section "I b - Getting started with Vaadin Spring without Spring Boot".

Answer (score 0):

To make Vaadin UI classes Spring managed beans, you can't use the default VaadinServlet you extend in your code snippet.

In most cases you don't actually need to present the servlet at all, but a context listener in Vaadin Spring will automatically create that for you. If you for some reason need some customisation for the servlet, then extend SpringVaadinServlet class instead of plain VaadinServlet.

If you are using Spring Boot, just remove the servlet declaration. Same with non-Boot configuration, but then you need to use @EnableVaadin in your configuration class. See the [Vaadin Spring tutorial](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/) for more instructions for setup if you are not using Spring Boot.